# What's the best way to collapse sparse data into single rows in R?

Tags: r, dplyr

I've got some transactional data that I'd like to transform in R.

```
df <- data.frame(
  customer_id = c(123, 123, 123),
  time = c(1, 2, 3),
  rec_type = c('contact', 'appointment', 'sale'),
  variable_1 = c('Yes', NA, NA),
  variable_2 = c(NA, 'No', NA),
  variable_3 = c(NA, NA, 'complete'))
```

The data looks like this:

```
customer_id     time    rec_type     variable_1     variable_2  variable_3
123             1        contact      Yes            NA          NA
123             2        appointment  NA             No          NA
123             3        sale         NA             NA          complete
```

Essentially, I'm trying to summarise the data on individuals by removing the time-specific and record-specific information and then collapse the unique data on an individual into a single row for the unique information so it would look like:

```
customer_id   variable_1    variable_2    variable_3
123           Yes           No            complete
```

What's the best way to do this in R?

Answer (score 2):

Easy with data.table

```
library(data.table)

setDT(mydata)[,.(na.omit(variable_1),na.omit(variable_2),na.omit(variable_3)), by=.(customer_id)]
```

Answer (score 2):

based on your example, you can just try:

```
df %>% 
  group_by(customer_id) %>%
  select( -time, -rec_type) %>%
  summarise_each(funs(na.omit(.)) )
```

p.s. `summarise_all()` might be a better option for future, when `summarise_each()` gets deprecated

Comment: or `df %>% group_by(customer_id) %>% summarise_each(funs(na.omit), starts_with("variable_"))` but this requires the result in each column to be a single non-NA value per customer